# How to use the kotlin compiler in command line which comes with Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I have Android studio version 3.4.1. I am able to build Android apps with the Kotlin language. I have heard that we can use Kotlin for creating standalone programs other than building android apps.

So, I want to know how to run the Kotlin compiler of Android studio to compile and run Kotlin programs in the command line, without downloading anything else?. I am using Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm on Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, not Windows. But maybe this can still help you.

In my Lubuntu, Android Studio put the Kotlin compiler in directory
$HOME/.AndroidStudio3.4/config/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc/bin .

So on Windows, make your file manager show hidden files and directories - because on Lubuntu, the "." in ".AndroidStudio3.4" means "hidden".

Go to your home or user directory and find a directory named "AndroidStudio3.4" or similar. Then just follow the path given above.

On Lubuntu, kotlinc (the compiler) isn't executable. If it's the same on Windows, give it execution permission.

I can't imagine that giving this permission affects how Kotlin works in Android Studio. But if you want to be on the safe side, install a separate [command line compiler](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/command-line.html) or [IntelliJ](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/#section=windows).

By the way, the Kotlin 1.3.40 REPL crashes (s. [issue KT-32085](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-32085)). If you need it, use Kotlin 1.3.31 .

Answer (score 1):

On Windows the folder is:

C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\Kotlin\kotlinc\bin